# Is it permitted for a boy and a girl to be bestfriends?

Tags: practical-islam, friendship

Is it permitted in islam for a boy and a girl to be bestfriends? I mean to speak, associate in the normal bestfriend like manner without physical contact?

P.S :- Please mind me if I'm asking something wrong!

Answer (score -1):

In the name of God, the Most Merciful, Most Gracious.

**Answer:**

**In the name of God, We praise Him, seek His help and ask for His forgiveness. Whoever God guides none can misguide, and whoever He allows to fall astray, none can guide them aright. We bear witness that there is none worthy of worship but God Alone, and we bear witness that Muhammad (saws) is His slave-servant and the seal of His Messengers.**

**Your question:** Is it permitted in islam for a boy and a girl to be bestfriends? I mean to speak, associate in the normal bestfriend like manner without physical contact?”

Yes, and there’s absolutely no sin in Islam if a believer boy wishes to become friend with a believing girl, but be careful of what you do because, God Almighty Says:

> ”Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, God is Acquainted with what they do”
>
> <sub><sup>[Surah An-Nur, 24:30][1]</sup></sub>

And if you want to become friend with a girl then, you have to respect few rules which is listed below.

**CONDITIONS ON HAVING A GIRLFRIEND**

> 1. Not to look at her private parts.
> 2. Not to have sex before marriage because it is Zina if you do this.
> 3. Not to think of having sex with her or her with you because, it is a temptation and it might leads you to do haram things( e.g. masturbate of what you saw and do Zina).
> 4. Don’t think of sexual scenes, if you do, then it might become haram.

If you do respect this list above, then you can continue your friendship. I hope I gave you a good answer.

Oh and, if you wish to become friend with a disbeliever, you can, because also prophet Muhammad became friend with a Christian lady named Marie and married her, and then she turned later to become a Muslim too like him(pbuh). So, yes, you can be with anybody you wish too, but be careful whom you choose friends because if you want to become friend with a disbeliever then you have to respect the following list I will give you.

> 1. As long as they don’t go against any elements of Islam.
> 2. As long as they( disbelievers) don’t mock/ make fun or insult any element of Islam
> 3. As long as they respect the religion Islam
> 4. As long as they truly respect you as who you are.

God  (Glorious is He and He is Exalted), the Exalted says in the Noble Qur'an:

> ”And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression."  [(Surah Al-Maeda, 5:2)][2]

God (Glorious is He and He is Exalted) the Exalted says in the Noble Qur'an:

> And (remember) the day when the unjust one shall bite his hands saying: O! Would that I had taken a way with the Messenger! O woe is me! Would that I had not taken such a one for a friend! Certainly he led me astray from the reminder after it had come to me;".  [(Surah Al-Furqan, 25:27-29)][3]

And God Almighty Says:

> ”And keep yourself (O Muhammad) patiently with those who call on their Lord (i.e. your companions who remember their Lord with glorification, praising in prayers, and other righteous deeds) morning and afternoon, seeking His Face”
>
> [al-Kahf 18:28][4]

But if you have selected wisely your friends, and they don’t go do as I gave you on the list above, then you can continue your friendship with them. But if they do then, you have to leave them and find a believing and righteous good friends, and if you see that your previous disbelieving friends starts to repent to God Almighty for their disbelief and shirk and all the evils they committed with sincerely, then you can stay with them(disbelievers) when they have become righteous believers. And you can pray for God To Guide then to the right path.

I hope this time is a good answer.

**Whatever written of Truth and benefit is only due to God’s Assistance and Guidance, and whatever of error is of me alone. God Alone Knows Best and He is the Only Source of Strength.**

Comment: @user519708 I will search more for it, but not now because in right now in Bucharest is night and it is 3:01 at night in Bucharest, so maybe tomorrow if I have some time,  I will make some researches for your question.

Comment: @user519708 Thanx, may God reward you too.

Comment: @user519708 Can you be more specific about this?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the main reason that I got a downvote?