# Is it haram for a Muslim girl and a Hindu boy to have a relationship?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships, behavior, friendship, human-rights

I met a girl on social site and met her only once during her birthday. The main problem is that she’s a Muslim girl and I belong to a Hindu family. She refused by saying that her religion doesn’t allow to practice such things especially keeping it as a secret, so called as “**Haram**” and also concluded saying that her parents would disown her and reputation of the family will go down in the society.

I never made any physical relationship with girl, not even a hug or sat very close together except just shaking hands just during her birthday. Never looked with bad intention and always lowered my eyes whenever I had a conversation to her.

Is it haram for a Muslim girl and a Hindu boy to have a relationship?

I have even asked [the question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/I-m-18-a-Hindu-boy-who-proposed-to-a-Muslim-girl-who-s-16-She-refused-by-saying-that-its-haram-to-have-a-secret-relation-Her-parents-would-disown-her-Her-reputation-will-go-down-in-the-society-Is-that-true-Why-Isnt), hope if it helps someone in a similiar situation :)

Comment: We can explain Islam's perspective (as this can be supported by Islamic evidence); you can form your own opinion of it being right or wrong.

Comment: I would be glad if you or someone else could explain me the same in reference to the perspective that whether the act is right or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Islam discourages unnecessary mixed-gender intermixing:

> No person (man) should be alone with a woman except when there is a Mahram with her.
> <sub>[Sahih Muslim 1341 c](https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/478)</sub>
>
> A man is not alone with a woman but the third of them is Ash-Shaitan.
> <sub>[Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2165](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/8) [grade: sahih]</sub>

So relationships like "girlfriend" and "boyfriend" are not appropriate, and would be considered haram (forbidden):

> In Islam, the male-female relationship is based on chastity. It is allowed to communicate with the opposite sex if the manners prescribed by Islamic law (shari'ah) are observed and for legally allowed purposes such as study, work or social activities. If a relationship exceeds these restrictions, it becomes prohibited.
> <sub>[Dar Al-Ifta](http://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=10757)</sub>

There's a zillion fatawa on topics like this, and they almost uniformly declare such relationships either haram or as temptation (leading to haram).

In practice, however, there are many mixed-gender interactions taking place between Muslims and non-Muslims.  Some Muslims can be a bit relaxed about the rules, and trust in Allah's forgiveness for minor inappropriate mixed-gender interactions (as per [Qur'an 4:31](https://quran.com/4/31)).  But after this, there's some hard barriers.

The Qur'an directly forbids marriage to a polytheist (and Hinduism has multiple [deities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_deities)):

> And do not marry polytheistic women until they believe. And a believing slave woman is better than a polytheist, even though she might please you. **And do not marry polytheistic men [to your women] until they believe.** And a believing slave is better than a polytheist, even though he might please you. Those invite [you] to the Fire, but Allah invites to Paradise and to forgiveness, by His permission. And He makes clear His verses to the people that perhaps they may remember.
> <sub>[Qur'an 2:221](https://quran.com/2/221)</sub>

So marriage is clearly haram (unless the man converts to Islam).

Such a marriage would not be Islamically recognized, and sex would be considered [fornication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zina) for which there is a prescribed punishment:

> **The [unmarried] woman or [unmarried] man found guilty of sexual intercourse - lash each one of them with a hundred lashes**, and do not be taken by pity for them in the religion of Allah, if you should believe in Allah and the Last Day. And let a group of the believers witness their punishment.
> <sub>[Qur'an 24:2](https://quran.com/24/2)</sub>

Finally, it's likely that there will be serious social ramifications of this relationship; Islam encourages *forbidding what is wrong* ([Qur'an 3:104](https://quran.com/3/104)).

---

You might also be interested in [*Advice to a Christian Man Who Wants to Marry a Muslim Woman*](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2012/07/22/advice-to-a-christian-man-who-wants-to-marry-a-muslim-woman/), since Christian husband + Muslim wife marriages are also forbidden in Islam.

Comment: I have read the entire answer and thanks for guiding me the right path. But according to the answer, I would like to quote the following "**It is allowed to communicate with the opposite sex if the manners prescribed by Islamic law (shari'ah) are observed and for legally allowed purposes such as study, work or social activities. If a relationship exceeds these restrictions, it becomes prohibited.**" So, I clearly state that I wanted to know the same. I have never gone beyond that indeed I assist her in her studies, help her to pursue her goals and lead her to success.

Comment: It’s none of my business what you have or haven’t done. I’m just answering the question (with what’s relevant for whoever might read it).

Comment: So, is it still a "**Haram**" for just being good or best friends? According to [Book 1, Hadith 1](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/1) states that **the value of an action depends on the intention behind it**. So if my intentions are good, is it still wrong?

Comment: In support to that, I would add that [Quran 17:25](https://quran.com/17/25) says that Your Lord is most knowing of what is within yourselves.

Comment: Mixed-gender friendships are blurry, and it depends on the circumstances.  The relevant post is [Does the Qur'an or Sunnah directly forbid male-female interactions aside from sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8185/17163).

Comment: There is another [relevant post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45329/is-it-permitted-for-a-boy-and-a-girl-to-be-bestfriends?rq=1) that I've found earlier but the answer is totally different there.So, now interaction with a girl on any social media platform is a **Haram**?

Comment: (You mean like what we're doing right now?)  It depends.  This is a Q&A site, so if you can't find your answer here already, then feel encouraged to ask (try to pinpoint a single, answerable question, though).